# difficult timing

Tags: electric-guitar

I want to ask a question about timing.  I include the link :

https://www.guitar.ch/tabs-pdf/tabs.php?pdf=Queen/BohemianRhapsody. The question is about the guitar solo which starts at bar 46.
How can you time bar 50 which contains demi semi quaver triplets and the like. I am struggling here, are there any timing gurus out there?

Comment: For this kind of thing, I tend to just listen to the track (slowed down if necessary) and try to work out the timing by ear. Once you have the note values, that's most of the battle.

Comment: Agreed. Think of it this way, Brian very probably never wrote it down at all, ever. It's a feel thing.

Comment: I am confused by the wording of your question but a few things are clear (1) Brian May fits the licks into a measure w/o losing time, (2) this is an attempt to express his "feeling" with discrete divisions of time which is not likely to work.  This is always the case (why we have things like "swing eights" rather than dotted triplets).  We try our best.  Now this may be very accurate if transcription s/w was used, but reading it looks like a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

Break down bar 50 into quarter notes.  Learn each quarter-note duration.  Then put it back together.  Also, try memorizing the rhythm before adding the pitches.  Just tap out the rhythm on your desk, or pluck an open string.

As other commenters have said, it's hard to notate such an improvised solo.  Better to *learn* it by ear, with the notation as a crutch for whatever details your ear misses.